# Anonymising/aggregating lat/long coordinates

Tags: geolocation, geospatial

I'm looking to display coordinates on a map. The coordinates are at a relatively fine resolution (3 decimal places), but I need to anonymise and aggregate them to a coarser resolution.

All the approaches I've seen run the risk of the coarse coordinates being the same as, or very close to, the original coordinates, since they rely on rounding or adding random noise to the original.

For example, with rounding:

```
53.401, -2.899 -> 53.4, -2.9 # less than 100m
```

With adding 'noise', e.g.:

```
lat = 53.456
// 'fuzz' in range -0.1 to 0.1
rnd = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * 0.1
newLat = lat + (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * 0.1
```

However if `rnd` is close to 0, then the coordinates don't 'move' much.

Is there a (simple) way to 'move' a coordinate in a random way a certain (minimum) distance from it's original location?

I've looked at other answers here but they don't seem to solve this issue of the new coordinates overlapping with the original coordinates:

[Rounding Lat and Long to Show Approximate Location in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269703/rounding-lat-and-long-to-show-approximate-location-in-google-maps)

[Is there any easy way to make GPS coordinates coarse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018788/is-there-any-easy-way-to-make-gps-coordinates-coarse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add random noise, you could displace every point by a fixed *distance* in a random *direction*. On a flat projection, for a radius r:

```
angle = Math.random() * 2 * PI
newLat = lat + (r * sin(angle))
newLon = lon + (r * cos(angle))
```

That would guarantee a fixed displacement (r) for every point, in an unpredictable direction.

Alternatively, you could anonymise by joining to a polygon at a coarser grain, and then plot the data by the *polygon* rather than the points. It could be as simple as a grid on a flat projection. Or something more sophisticated such as the [Australian Statistical Geography Standard](https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/standards/australian-statistical-geography-standard-asgs-edition-3/jul2021-jun2026) which offers multiple choices, the most granular being a "mesh block" which they guarantee to always contain 30-60 dwellings.

Comment: Thanks - I'd considered mapping onto a polygon, but I also have to make public a single coordinate, hence this not being quite enough. However the fixed distance/random direction solution is perfect and easy to implement!

Comment: (and if I can ask a (hopefully simple) question - why is it multiplied by sin for lat, and cos for lon?)

Comment: I had to look it up :-) but there's a nice diagram [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) at the top right. If the radius is 1 then the y value (i.e. latitude) is sin(angle) and the x value (corresponding to longitude) is cos(angle). If you're far north you'll get a rather oval distribution but as long as you keep the radius pretty small it should be good and simple

Answer (score 1):

> All the approaches I've seen run the risk of the coarse coordinates
> being the same as, or very close to, the original coordinates, since
> they rely on rounding or adding random noise to the original.

Could you explain, what's the risk that you are concerned about here? Yes, the coarse coordinate might happen to be the same, but it is still anonymized - whoever sees the coarse data would not know if it is coincidentally close or not. All they know is that the actual location is within some distance R_max from the coarse location.

Re the other solution,

> displace every point by a fixed distance in a random direction

I would say it is much worse: here it would be easy to discover the fixed displacement distance by knowing just a single original location. Then, for any "coarse" location, we would know the original is on thin **unfilled** circle centered on the "coarse" location - much worse than the **filled** circle or rectangle in the original solution.

At the very least, I would use random radius, maybe don't allow it to be zero, if you are concerned about coincidental collision (but you should not be). E.g. this varies the radius from `r_max / 2` to `r_max`:

```
r = (Math.random() + 1) * r_max / 2;
```

and then you can use this random radius with Schepo's solution.

Comment: For GDPR my understanding is that it is not enough for data to be statistically likely to be anonymised - it must be *actually* anonymised. While it is practically unlikely to have coincidentally close data, or to be able to exploit it if there is, the legal test is much stricter. The option of randomising angle and distance does make sense though!